# Dynamically update key in array of objects + mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I wouldnt be surprised if this has been asked before but I have not found a working example.

Basically I have a set of Boolean data inside of an array of objects and I would like to reuse my API routes/logic to update array of objects dynamically

**Data Example:**

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "posts": [
       { "_id": d323d32, "published": true, "homepage": false, (...moreBooleanData) }, 
       { "_id": ffwfwfwc, "published": true, "homepage": false, (...moreBooleanData) },
       { "_id": fdscsdad, "published": true, "homepage": false, (...moreBooleanData) }
    ]
}
```

**Mongoose Query**

```
await Project.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: 1 },
    { $set: { "posts.$[el].published": isChecked } },
    {
        arrayFilters: [{ "el._id": postid }],
        new: true
    }
)
```

The problem is in this line `"posts.$[el].published": isChecked`. Here I have the key `published` hard coded but I would like to have this key dynamic so I can grab it from the body of my post request

```
const { DYNAMIC_KEY , isChecked } = req.body

"posts.$[el].$[DYNAMIC_KEY]": isChecked`
```

I have tried formatting the `$set` string with backticks, building it outside the query and passing it as 1 variable all without success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using bracket notation:

```js
router.post("/project/:id/:postid", async (req, res) => {

  const { isChecked, dynamicKey } = req.body;
  let set = `posts.$[el].${dynamicKey}`;

  console.log(set);

  const result = await Project.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.id },
    { $set: { [set]: isChecked } },
    {
      arrayFilters: [{ "el._id": req.params.postid }],
      new: true
    }
  );

  res.send(result);
});
```

I have a project document with these 3 posts:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5def81070066dc23e05b816e"),
    "posts" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5def81070066dc23e05b8171"),
            "published" : true,
            "homepage" : false
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5def81070066dc23e05b8170"),
            "published" : true,
            "homepage" : false
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5def81070066dc23e05b816f"),
            "published" : true,
            "homepage" : false
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I send a post request to my router  `../project/5def81070066dc23e05b816e/5def81070066dc23e05b8170`  with this body:

```
{
  "isChecked": false,
  "dynamicKey": "published"
}
```

The result is like this: ( post's (with id 5def81070066dc23e05b8170) published value is updated to false)

```
{
    "_id": "5def81070066dc23e05b816e",
    "posts": [
        {
            "_id": "5def81070066dc23e05b8171",
            "published": true,
            "homepage": false
        },
        {
            "_id": "5def81070066dc23e05b8170",
            "published": false,
            "homepage": false
        },
        {
            "_id": "5def81070066dc23e05b816f",
            "published": true,
            "homepage": false
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: This might be the best answer Ive seen in terms of how thorough it was. Thank you very much, I had something similar to this before but I did not have my built string wrapped in brackets like you did here `{ $set: { [set]: isChecked } }`. Thanks again